Relaychain/Parachain Compatability: What Guarantees does Polkadot give?
What guarantees does Polkadot give to parachains regarding compatability. Will polkadot-v1.y.z always be compatible with a parachain built on polkadot-v1.0.0? If not, by what system should parachain teams update their chains?

Yes Polkadot is backward compatible. In the end it is the new features, such as asynchronous backing (12 -> 6s block time), that makes a parachain want to upgrade.
